# Connection to localhost fails

Tags: apache, localhost, vhosts

I set up /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf as follows:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80

# Listen for virtual host requests on all IP addresses
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName localhost
        DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents/
</VirtualHost>
```

In /Library/WebServer/Documents/ is the standard index.html.en file which was shown perfectly in the browser before I included the httpd-vhosts.conf into my httpd.conf.

The connection to localhost fails using both, Chrome and Firefox. Is the setup correct? What else could go wrong?

Comment: Does apache even start? 'cause not being able to connect seems to me it fails on a config error.

Comment: apachectl start gets me org.apache.httpd: Already loaded. So i think it starts. I also restarted it several times. If I not include the  httpd-vhosts.conf everything works like a charm. What else could I look for?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. I couldn't state further information because I just didn't know where I could look for the problem. This post put me in the right way:

http://macosx.com/forums/mac-os-x-system-mac-software/299851-apache-wont-start-up.html

```
sudo apachectl configtest
```

Gave me an syntax error within the httpd.conf file. After fixing it everything worked. The important thing is the opportunity to run a configtest.